# GRUB and LVM stripped / volume

Tags: grub2, lubuntu, raid, lvm, eeepc

I am attempting to install lubuntu on a very old eeepc. It has a 4Gb SSD and a 16Gb SD Card.

I created a 512MB partition on the ssd to hold the boot partition sda1 (ext4). and I created an LVM volume group comprised of the remaing from sda (sda2 3.5GB), and two physical volumes on sdc (sdc1 3.5Gb; sdc2 ~15.5Gb).

In this volume group I created a logical volume that is stripped across sda2 and sdc1, where I intend to mount the root of my system, and a linear logical volume where I will mount /home.

Before I proceed with the installation I am still checking the file system for bad blocks. what is taking ages... While this is taking its time I wonder if I will need to do anything special when installing grub, so that it plays well with my stripped lvm volume group.

Comment: You haven't given any details on the Lubuntu for a start, are you talking about a `ubiquity` installed Lubuntu, *di* (*debian installer*) version of Lubuntu, or modern `calamares` installer version of Lubuntu.  Lubuntu currently has three supported installers (depending on release; you didn't provide an intended release so we cannot even narrow that down to what's available for *unstated* release).

Comment: I am using a 18.04 ncurses based debian installer.

Comment: Sorry I haven't used that installer as you are (that ISO hasn't been updated since initial 18.04 release, and I wasn't involved with Lubuntu or flavor testing then). I can't advise sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is for 18.04 LTS.

I managed to install lubuntu on this machine with the following config:

internal ssd: 4Gb lvm physical volume (sda1)
sdcard:

- 500 Mb lvm physical volume(sdb1)
- 4Gb lvm physical volume (sdb2)
- 9.5GM lvm physycal volume (sdb3)
- 2Gb swap partition

which were used as follows:

- boot volume group/logical only comprised of sdb1 - please notice that if there are any lvm partitions it is important that /boot is also in an lvm partition, to force the grub autoconfiguration to be prepared to handle lvm  filesystems. Maybe boot could simply belong in the root volume group. Though it would have to be expicitly linear and contained in the same partition as the mbr.
- root volume group/logical volume, comprised of two sections:

  - sda1 and sdb2 striped.
  - sdb3 linear

The mbr config was installed on the sdcard.